# copy and paste files within android

Tags: java, android

so Im trying to make a file manager android app that allows me to copy and paste selected files. I found a useful method for doing this online but it doesnt seem to work for me. If you could offer any suggestions on how I can fix my problem that would be great, thank you

public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

}

Comment: How *it doesnt seem to work*, are you getting specific exception? paste the Stacktrace here to get better help

Comment: thanks, Im getting a file not found exception on my file and then it says open has failed EISDIR (is a directory), does this mean that I cant copy files into another directory because it can't open them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your function, it will simply copy a file (or rename it) from location to another.

Referring to the error you are getting `(is a directory)`, I believe you are specifing the wrong parameter in the destination, it has to be a filename **not** a directory

So to use this function correctly you can do something like:

```
 copy(new File("Director1","filename"), new File("Directory2","filename"));
```

Or you can use it to `rename` a file (not efficient solution), e.g.

```
     copy(new File("Director1","filename"), new File("Directory1","new_filename"));
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I cant seem to get that to work either, the app just crashes

Comment: What is the exception? I assume that you specify *real* folder name in the parameters, since the code here is just for illustration. Also, make sure that your app has the required permission i.e. `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: copy(selectedFiles.get(0), new File(currentLocation.getPath(),"myFile.txt"));, this is the code i use to call it, selectedFiles is an ArrayList of files and currentLocation is the directory i wish to paste the file into, if you could advise me on this, it would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: You need to add the exception `Stacktrace`, to know the reason that crashes your app.